# luamesh+luamplib not working in all cases

Tags: tikz-pgf, bugs, luamplib

## A bug report

Is it fixable?

I've installed the latest version of `gmsh` v4.5.6 (http://gmsh.info/) and I'm trying MWE from the `luamesh` package. I'm using the `maillage.geo` and `maillage.msh` files from the `luamesh` package v 0.5 from 2017-02-09 located in the `/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/luamesh/` subfolder.

My used `luamplib` is v2.20.5 from 2020-02-24. TeXLive 2020, Xubuntu 18.04.

This code works well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamesh}
\begin{document}
\drawGmsh[tikz]{maillage.msh}
\end{document}
```

This code isn't producing an expected PDF file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamesh}
\begin{document}
\drawGmsh{maillage.msh}
\end{document}
```

The format of the `maillage.msh` file is version 2 ASCII.  If we try to export `msh` in version 4 ASCII (default option), none of those two examples is working.

## Summary

Version 2 ASCII with `[tikz]`: All is working well.

Version 2 ASCII without `[tikz]`:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
\\drawGmsh ...eshvaldg@color ")}\else \mplibcolor 
                                              {\luameshmpcolor }{\luames...
l.4 \drawGmsh{maillage-version2.msh}
```

Version 4 ASCII with `[tikz]`:

```
luamesh/luamesh.lua:534: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (field '?
')
stack traceback:
...pivo/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/luamesh/luamesh.lua:534: in function '
readGmsh'
.../texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/luamesh/luamesh-tex.lua:767: in function '
drawGmshTikZ'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\\drawGmsh ...ldg@scale ","\luameshvaldg@color ")}
                                              \else \mplibcolor     {\luames...

l.4 \drawGmsh[tikz]{maillage-version4.msh}
```

Version 4 ASCII without `[tikz]`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\drawGmsh ...eshvaldg@color ")}\else \mplibcolor 
                                              {\luameshmpcolor }{\luames...
l.4 \drawGmsh{maillage-version4.msh}
```

The `maillage-version2.msh` (it's slighty different from `maillage.msh` in last several decimal digits, but the structure is the same):

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
49
1 0 0 0
2 3 0 0
3 0 3 0
4 0.4693033963404087 2.963065021592229 0
5 0.927050985688588 2.853169548052449 0
6 1.361971502971016 2.673019570653173 0
7 1.763355761304841 2.427050979908132 0
8 2.121320348549485 2.121320338569801 0
9 2.427050986323072 1.763355752475434 0
10 2.673019574643209 1.361971495140128 0
11 2.853169549732512 0.9270509805178855 0
12 2.963065021991164 0.4693033938216338 0
13 0 0.499999999997822 0
14 0 0.9999999999960245 0
15 0 1.499999999994285 0
16 0 1.999999999996158 0
17 0 2.499999999998079 0
18 2.500000000003167 0 0
19 2.000000000001941 0 0
20 1.500000000004168 0 0
21 1.00000000000281 0 0
22 0.5000000000014051 0 0
23 0.4324208618787972 1.254526258340053 0
24 1.964179242223375 1.677567546495472 0
25 1.277646354647664 0.4113155914951311 0
26 1.331385884279466 2.208153696956179 0
27 2.408333487391826 0.9570142841403682 0
28 0.4806120485258751 2.21192748111512 0
29 2.199842564949955 0.4740583806850691 0
30 0.4383482110825652 1.744285474319584 0
31 0.8583628800522819 1.500701899336962 0
32 0.8225535882961561 0.9953960076673578 0
33 1.281083415964582 1.237393204562323 0
34 0.8915779045171567 1.969788703743087 0
35 0.4204627438899584 0.7566691502573124 0
36 1.736929708778206 0.4257397652798222 0
37 1.278622231642468 1.746395721121067 0
38 1.524726655147985 0.8206048256661349 0
39 1.76486136704753 1.246517525545464 0
40 0.7904684345601101 0.4733411038827577 0
41 0.9693508624533295 2.418048746306837 0
42 1.982120034150953 0.8846091911536498 0
43 1.677597399498234 1.959155701651377 0
44 2.21890810757101 1.334757699095549 0
45 2.584882124813725 0.5654854078329913 0
46 0.5692634586016403 2.589242159412943 0
47 0.3706919352530829 0.3706919352521562 0
48 1.606720928989769 1.574445926857611 0
49 1.141924419829695 0.779315042507347 0
$EndNodes
$Elements
99
1 15 2 0 1 1
2 15 2 0 2 2
3 15 2 0 3 3
4 1 2 0 1 3 4
5 1 2 0 1 4 5
6 1 2 0 1 5 6
7 1 2 0 1 6 7
8 1 2 0 1 7 8
9 1 2 0 1 8 9
10 1 2 0 1 9 10
11 1 2 0 1 10 11
12 1 2 0 1 11 12
13 1 2 0 1 12 2
14 1 2 0 2 1 13
15 1 2 0 2 13 14
16 1 2 0 2 14 15
17 1 2 0 2 15 16
18 1 2 0 2 16 17
19 1 2 0 2 17 3
20 1 2 0 3 2 18
21 1 2 0 3 18 19
22 1 2 0 3 19 20
23 1 2 0 3 20 21
24 1 2 0 3 21 22
25 1 2 0 3 22 1
26 2 2 0 6 17 4 46
27 2 2 0 6 12 18 45
28 2 2 0 6 12 2 18
29 2 2 0 6 3 4 17
30 2 2 0 6 42 39 44
31 2 2 0 6 27 42 44
32 2 2 0 6 28 17 46
33 2 2 0 6 18 29 45
34 2 2 0 6 35 32 40
35 2 2 0 6 27 29 42
36 2 2 0 6 40 32 49
37 2 2 0 6 34 28 41
38 2 2 0 6 34 26 37
39 2 2 0 6 29 27 45
40 2 2 0 6 23 30 31
41 2 2 0 6 23 15 30
42 2 2 0 6 13 14 35
43 2 2 0 6 30 28 34
44 2 2 0 6 41 28 46
45 2 2 0 6 29 19 36
46 2 2 0 6 31 30 34
47 2 2 0 6 16 28 30
48 2 2 0 6 16 17 28
49 2 2 0 6 18 19 29
50 2 2 0 6 14 23 35
51 2 2 0 6 20 25 36
52 2 2 0 6 32 31 33
53 2 2 0 6 14 15 23
54 2 2 0 6 37 26 43
55 2 2 0 6 23 31 32
56 2 2 0 6 19 20 36
57 2 2 0 6 15 16 30
58 2 2 0 6 20 21 25
59 2 2 0 6 31 34 37
60 2 2 0 6 26 34 41
61 2 2 0 6 6 7 26
62 2 2 0 6 8 9 24
63 2 2 0 6 23 32 35
64 2 2 0 6 10 11 27
65 2 2 0 6 39 24 44
66 2 2 0 6 33 31 37
67 2 2 0 6 29 36 42
68 2 2 0 6 21 22 40
69 2 2 0 6 38 33 39
70 2 2 0 6 36 25 38
71 2 2 0 6 37 43 48
72 2 2 0 6 5 6 41
73 2 2 0 6 25 21 40
74 2 2 0 6 6 26 41
75 2 2 0 6 22 1 47
76 2 2 0 6 1 13 47
77 2 2 0 6 32 33 49
78 2 2 0 6 38 39 42
79 2 2 0 6 33 38 49
80 2 2 0 6 25 40 49
81 2 2 0 6 36 38 42
82 2 2 0 6 7 8 43
83 2 2 0 6 9 10 44
84 2 2 0 6 26 7 43
85 2 2 0 6 8 24 43
86 2 2 0 6 24 9 44
87 2 2 0 6 10 27 44
88 2 2 0 6 39 33 48
89 2 2 0 6 27 11 45
90 2 2 0 6 33 37 48
91 2 2 0 6 11 12 45
92 2 2 0 6 13 35 47
93 2 2 0 6 4 5 46
94 2 2 0 6 40 22 47
95 2 2 0 6 24 39 48
96 2 2 0 6 43 24 48
97 2 2 0 6 35 40 47
98 2 2 0 6 5 41 46
99 2 2 0 6 38 25 49
$EndElements
```

The `maillage-version4.msh` looks like this:

```
$MeshFormat
4.1 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Entities
3 3 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 
2 3 0 0 0 
3 0 3 0 0 
1 0 2.220446049250313e-16 0 3 3 0 0 2 3 -2 
2 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 2 1 -3 
3 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 2 2 -1 
6 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 3 1 3 2 
$EndEntities
$Nodes
7 49 1 49
0 1 0 1
1
0 0 0
0 2 0 1
2
3 0 0
0 3 0 1
3
0 3 0
1 1 0 9
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
0.4693033963404087 2.963065021592229 0
0.927050985688588 2.853169548052449 0
1.361971502971016 2.673019570653173 0
1.763355761304841 2.427050979908132 0
2.121320348549485 2.121320338569801 0
2.427050986323072 1.763355752475434 0
2.673019574643209 1.361971495140128 0
2.853169549732512 0.9270509805178855 0
2.963065021991164 0.4693033938216338 0
1 2 0 5
13
14
15
16
17
0 0.499999999997822 0
0 0.9999999999960245 0
0 1.499999999994285 0
0 1.999999999996158 0
0 2.499999999998079 0
1 3 0 5
18
19
20
21
22
2.500000000003167 0 0
2.000000000001941 0 0
1.500000000004168 0 0
1.00000000000281 0 0
0.5000000000014051 0 0
2 6 0 27
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
0.4324208618787972 1.254526258340053 0
1.964179242223375 1.677567546495472 0
1.277646354647664 0.4113155914951311 0
1.331385884279466 2.208153696956179 0
2.408333487391826 0.9570142841403682 0
0.4806120485258751 2.21192748111512 0
2.199842564949955 0.4740583806850691 0
0.4383482110825652 1.744285474319584 0
0.8583628800522819 1.500701899336962 0
0.8225535882961561 0.9953960076673578 0
1.281083415964582 1.237393204562323 0
0.8915779045171567 1.969788703743087 0
0.4204627438899584 0.7566691502573124 0
1.736929708778206 0.4257397652798222 0
1.278622231642468 1.746395721121067 0
1.524726655147985 0.8206048256661349 0
1.76486136704753 1.246517525545464 0
0.7904684345601101 0.4733411038827577 0
0.9693508624533295 2.418048746306837 0
1.982120034150953 0.8846091911536498 0
1.677597399498234 1.959155701651377 0
2.21890810757101 1.334757699095549 0
2.584882124813725 0.5654854078329913 0
0.5692634586016403 2.589242159412943 0
0.3706919352530829 0.3706919352521562 0
1.606720928989769 1.574445926857611 0
1.141924419829695 0.779315042507347 0
$EndNodes
$Elements
7 99 1 99
0 1 15 1
1 1 
0 2 15 1
2 2 
0 3 15 1
3 3 
1 1 1 10
4 3 4 
5 4 5 
6 5 6 
7 6 7 
8 7 8 
9 8 9 
10 9 10 
11 10 11 
12 11 12 
13 12 2 
1 2 1 6
14 1 13 
15 13 14 
16 14 15 
17 15 16 
18 16 17 
19 17 3 
1 3 1 6
20 2 18 
21 18 19 
22 19 20 
23 20 21 
24 21 22 
25 22 1 
2 6 2 74
26 17 4 46 
27 12 18 45 
28 12 2 18 
29 3 4 17 
30 42 39 44 
31 27 42 44 
32 28 17 46 
33 18 29 45 
34 35 32 40 
35 27 29 42 
36 40 32 49 
37 34 28 41 
38 34 26 37 
39 29 27 45 
40 23 30 31 
41 23 15 30 
42 13 14 35 
43 30 28 34 
44 41 28 46 
45 29 19 36 
46 31 30 34 
47 16 28 30 
48 16 17 28 
49 18 19 29 
50 14 23 35 
51 20 25 36 
52 32 31 33 
53 14 15 23 
54 37 26 43 
55 23 31 32 
56 19 20 36 
57 15 16 30 
58 20 21 25 
59 31 34 37 
60 26 34 41 
61 6 7 26 
62 8 9 24 
63 23 32 35 
64 10 11 27 
65 39 24 44 
66 33 31 37 
67 29 36 42 
68 21 22 40 
69 38 33 39 
70 36 25 38 
71 37 43 48 
72 5 6 41 
73 25 21 40 
74 6 26 41 
75 22 1 47 
76 1 13 47 
77 32 33 49 
78 38 39 42 
79 33 38 49 
80 25 40 49 
81 36 38 42 
82 7 8 43 
83 9 10 44 
84 26 7 43 
85 8 24 43 
86 24 9 44 
87 10 27 44 
88 39 33 48 
89 27 11 45 
90 33 37 48 
91 11 12 45 
92 13 35 47 
93 4 5 46 
94 40 22 47 
95 24 39 48 
96 43 24 48 
97 35 40 47 
98 5 41 46 
99 38 25 49 
$EndElements
```

## Observations

- The structure of the `msh` file changed, comparing version 2 and version 4, the `luamesh` package is collapsing.
- The `luamplib` package changed at some point, I guess, maybe some switching option will help with that unknown color command? Adding `\usepackage{xcolor}` didn't help.

## Update 1

This partially helped with version 2 without `tikz`, although there are many extra characters in the document:

```
\let\mplibcolor=\mpcolor
\def\luameshmpcolor{black}
```

## Update 2

This is a workaround for version 2 without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luamesh}
\def\mplibcolor#1{}
\def\luameshmpcolor{blue}
\begin{document}
\drawGmsh[color=]{maillage-version2.msh}
\end{document}
```

## Update 3

This is conversion from format 4 to format 2:

```
gmsh maillage-version4.msh -save -format msh2 -o maillage-v4-to-v2.msh
```

This worked for me after that /Metapost/:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamesh}
\def\mplibcolor#1{}
\def\luameshmpcolor{blue}
\begin{document}
\drawGmsh[color=]{maillage-v4-to-v2.msh}
\end{document}
```

And this part worked for me with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamesh}
%\def\mplibcolor#1{}
%\def\luameshmpcolor{blue}
\begin{document}
\drawGmsh[tikz,color=blue]{maillage-v4-to-v2.msh}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well obviously the package doesn't work correctly. So sent the author a bug report.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Bug report sent.  It looks that there are minor issues in luamplib as well.  I am not going to bother LuaTeX team members, the conversion from version 4 to version 2 does the job, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the report. I update the package (to version 0.6), I was not aware of the change of luamplib, neither of the new MSH ASCII file format. 
Everything is working now (with version 0.6):

https://ctan.org/pkg/luamesh